# Avoid component re-rendering when passing props to child component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

I'm relatively new to React and I'm stuck at the moment. Basically I'm fetching data from an API and populating a MAPBOX with Markers recursively. I have the `App` component which is where I fetch the data from, a `Map` component where I set up the map and all its properties and then I have `InfoHeader` component to display some more data I grab from the API.

The way I pass the data I want to `InfoHeader` which is stored in state, is through props once one of the markers in the map is clicked.

**Current Issue:**
Once I click the marker I am having the entire `Map` component rerendering and therefore the popup never shows and even though the data is passed correctly to `InfoHeader`, I don't want `Map` re-rendering, only `InfoHeader`

I have tried using React.memo but so far no luck.

**Code**

**Map.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import InfoHeader from './InfoHeader'

mapboxgl.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoibGVob3VkaW5pIiwiYSI6ImNram43b3FhZTNzYWUydnNjd21zcmJ1d2QifQ.ouLhKn6B6pzmbZJtymQIcg"

const Map = React.memo(({data}) => {

    const mapRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapRef.current,

            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
            center: [-104.9876, 39.7405],
            zoom: 1.5,
        })

       //Marker logic in async func 
       addMarkerToMap(data, map)
        

          // add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'bottom-right');


        return () => {
            //cleanup when unmounting
            map.remove()
        }
    })
    
    //state to be passed to InfoHeader
    const [population, setPopulation] = useState()
    const [infected, setInfected] = useState()
    const [recovered, setRecovered] = useState()

    const addMarkerToMap = async (mapData, map) =>  {
        if(Object.keys(mapData).length) {
            mapData.forEach(el => {
                const {countryInfo, country, cases, population, recovered, deaths} = el
                const {lat, long, flag} = countryInfo
                console.log(el)
                const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                .setLngLat([long, lat])
                .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(
                    `<img style="width: 100%" src=${flag} alt="flag"/> <h1 style="text-align:center; color: #fcfcfc">${country}</h1>
                    <p>Population: ${population}</p>
                    <p>Number of cases: ${cases}</p>
                    <p>Deaths: ${deaths}
                    <p>Recovered: ${recovered}</p>
                `))
                .addTo(map)
                marker.getElement().addEventListener('click', () => {
                    setPopulation(population)
                    setInfected(cases)
                    setRecovered(recovered)
                })
            })
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className="map-wrapper">
            <InfoHeader
                population = {population}
                infected = {infected}
                recovered = {recovered}
            />
            <div className="map-container" ref={mapRef}>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
})

export default Map
```

**InfoHeader.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const InfoHeader = ({population, infected, recovered}) => {

    return(
        <div className="infoHeader-wrapper">
            <div className="infoHeader-population">
                <h2 className="info-title">Population</h2>
                <p className="info-data">{population}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="infoHeader-infected">
                <h2 className="info-title">Infected</h2>
                <p className="info-data">{infected}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="infoHeader-recovered">
                <h2 className="info-title">Recovered</h2>
                <p className="info-data">{recovered}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default InfoHeader
```

Any help would be amazing, even if it is pointing me to some resource to read more about whatever I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid your `useEffect` hook from rerunning again, add an empty array as the second parameter.

From the docs of React.js on [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapRef.current,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
    center: [-104.9876, 39.7405],
    zoom: 1.5,
  })

  //Marker logic in async func 
  addMarkerToMap(data, map)

  // add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'bottom-right');

  return () => {
    //cleanup when unmounting
    map.remove()
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Just as a quick edit, I had to put data in the dependency array in order to render the markers